# Elementary Geometry: Prove that ABCD is a tangential quadrilateral!

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

The task is as follows:

> ABCD is a convex quadrilateral with points E, F, G and H on its sides AB, BC, CD and DA so that they divide the respective side at the ratio of the adjacent sides, so $$\frac {AE}{EB}=\frac {DA}{BC}, \frac {BF}{FC}=\frac {AB}{CD}, \frac {CG}{GD}=\frac {BC}{DA}, \frac {DH}{HA}=\frac {CD}{AB}.$$
>   Show that ABCD is a tangential quadrilateral if and only if EFGH is a cyclic quadrilateral.

I have already shown that if ABCD is a tangential quadrilateral, EFGH is a cyclic quadrilateral. But I have not succeeded in proving the reverse direction yet. I cannot figure out what to make out of these ratios. Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the reverse direction, not only is $ABCD$ a tangential quadrilateral, but also the points $E,F,G,H$ turn out to be exactly the points of tangency.

Comment: I also observed this when drawing a sketch of the set-up and thus thought of proving that ME is perpendicular to AB (where M is the centre of the circle through E, F, G and H) and analogously for the other sides of ABCD but this did not work either. I just did not figure out where I had to use these ratios ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

With some manipulation, we obtain
$$\frac{CG}{CF}=\frac{DG}{DH}=\frac{AE}{AF}=\frac{BE}{BF}=\frac{AB+CD}{AD+BC}.\tag{1}$$

Without loss of generality, suppose that $AB+CD\ge AD+BC$. Then from (1), we get that the green angles are not larger than the red angles. However, their corresponding sums are both $180^\circ$ because $EFGH$ are cyclic. Thus all the ratios in (1) are equal to $1$ and $ABCD$ is a tangential quadrilateral.

Comment: this is very clever. But for future reference, you should probably make it clear that you are not assuming the green angles are equal to each other.

Comment: That's a beautiful proof! I don't think I could have come up with it. Thank you very much!